# Несколько поочередных запросов на ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django, ajax-load

Я новичок в JS и JQuery, возникла необходимость делать запросы к базе данных, худо-бедно нашел код, который работает у меня, но проблема в том, что код делает правильно только один запрос, а мне необходимо сделать пару последовательных запросов на разные страницы. 
Второй запрос должен использовать данные из первого запроса. В первом запросе ответом придет что-то типа `Видимые данные`.
**Необходимо для второго запроса взять значение value из первого ответа и отослать его дальше на другую страницу.**
После подобным образом вывести в документ.
Ниже мой код, он отсылает 2 запроса как мне и нужно, но во втором запросе он отсылает дословно `?group_id=`, необходимо `?group_id=1 или ?group_id=2`

```js
$("#client").change(function() {

  var url = $("#indexForm").attr("data-tgetc");
  var company_id = $(this).val();

  $.ajax({
    url: url,
    data: {
      'company_id': company_id
    },

    success: function(data) {
      $("#company").html(data);

      //начало 2 запроса
      $("#company").ready(function() {
        var url = $("#indexForm").attr("data-tget");
        var group_id = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
          url: url,
          data: {
            'group_id': group_id
          },
          success: function(data) {
            $("#groupcomp").html(data);
          }
        });

      });
      //конец 2 запроса
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container" style="margin-top:50px">
  <h2 class="text-center">Antony CRM</h2>
  <br><br>
  <form method="post" id="indexForm" data-tgetc="{% url 'tgetc' %}" data-tget="{% url 'tget' %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <label>Client</label>
    <select name="client" id="client" class="form-control mb-4">
      <option value="" id="remove">Сделай выбор</option>
      {% for i in clientss %}
      <option value="{{i.company_id}}">{{i.client}}</option>
      {% endfor %}
    </select>

    <label>Company</label>
    <div id="company" class="form-control">

    </div>
    <br>

    <label>Group of Company</label>
    <div id="groupcomp" class="form-control">

    </div>

    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="form-control btn btn-primary">
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А зачем вы данные из первого запроса тащите в html? Просто чтобы в следующей строке их оттуда достать? Вы получили данные из первого запроса ну и отправляйте сразу второй.

```
$("#client").change(function() {
  const url = $("#indexForm").attr("data-tgetc");
  const company_id = $(this).val();

  $.ajax({
    url: url,
    data: {
      company_id,
    },
    success: function(group_id) {
      console.log('Ура! Данные из первого запроса:', group_id);
      $.ajax({
        url: url,
        data: {
          group_id,
        },
        success: function(data) {
          console.log('Ура! Данные из второго запроса:', data);
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
```

Если и этот скрипт отправит пустой grop_id, то посмотрите консоль, возможно вам из первого запроса что-то не то приходит.

Comment: Ответ не выводит число какое-то, он выводит целый тег, вот что вышло в консоль, в одном из примеров: 
Ура! Данные из первого запроса:  
<option value="2">Пк Сев-Зап</option>
По сути, мне отсюда надо достать значение value, направить на другую страницу, получить еще один такой тег и вставить на исходный документ

Comment: Я пытался выполнить данный скрипт 2 раза подряд, только подставляя сюда данные из следующего div, но он как-будто не видит их

Comment: А еще, запросы идут на разные страницы, тут не с одной и той же страницы, у меня их 2

Comment: Роман, в консоль попадает то, что вы получили из API. Если вы видите в консоли HTML тег, то значит или вы или тот кто делал API его туда отправили - это абсолютно идиотская практика. Отправлять нужно значения - что-то типа `{"name": "Пк Сев-Зап", "value": "2"}` потом делать `const result = JSON.parse(data)` и работать с этим - брать отсюда значения для следующего запроса, формировать DOM и т.д.

Comment: Я думаю, дальнейшем это будет изменено, но есть ли какие-то варианты на данный момент с тем, что имеется?

Comment: Ну вообще, в слое "#company" нет ведь ничего. Куда вы пихаете свои "<option value="2">Пк Сев-Зап</option>"? там же нет селекта.

Comment: Я селект заменил на div, указал туда id="company", внешне разницы нет, зато возможности выбора нет, что мне и нужно по сути

Comment: Ну а value то вы как получите из div? Говорю вам, у вас с API проблемы. Это надо переделывать первым делом. Вы сами себе геморой создаете.

Comment: Тогда я сейчас сделаю изменения в API и чуть позже напишу сюда же

Comment: В общем я изменил API, теперь он выдает список в формате JSON и я даже получил то, что хотел, делаю 2 поочередных вопроса, получаю результаты, записываю их в переменные. Теперь хочется выводить их в документ, например так <option value="переменная а">переменная b</option>. То есть, хочу выводить новый тег, подставлять в value свою переменную и внутрь тега, у в примере это переменные a и b.
P.S. Отметил ваш ответ, спасибо за помощь.

Comment: Ну дак вставляйте. Вы ведь вроде вставку в html освоили. `$("#company").html(\`<option value="${a}">${b}</option>\`);` как-то так и вперед

Comment: Все, понял принцип, спасибо еще раз большое!